# Django - Does the default Django User model have any unique fields?

Tags: django

I know I should be able to find this in the Django documentation but I was having a difficult time. In my application I need to query the default Django User model but I need to do it in a way that it will only ever return one result. For this to happen one of the fields need to be unique.

Does the Django User Model have any unique fields I can use?

Thanks.

Comment: I did not know that field existed. That worked, thanks. If you want to expand upon it a little bit in an answer I can mark it right.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does: username must be unique, otherwise there would be no way of logging in a specific user.

And, as agconti points out, all models have a `pk` field which must be unique by deifnition.

Comment: That is a very good point. I just noticed with my Facebook authentication the username was just the first and last name put together so I was worried about the occurrence of two of my users having the same name.